# PostgreSql query checking two values

Tags: php, sql, database

I was trying to accomplish an autocomplete feature for combo box, I did that by following http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/forum-search.html

**My php query:**

```
if (!$con) {
    throw new Exception("Error in connection to DB");
     }

$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM students WHERE first_name ILIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = pg_query($con, $sql);
ORDER BY name ASC";


 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
       {  
        $names[] = array('name' => $row[0]);

       }

$name_list = array();
$name_list['success']       = true;
$name_list['names']     = $names;


$name_list['totalCount']    = count( $name_list['names'] );

echo json_encode($name_list);
```

In my case, the user could type last name instead of first name of the student, So I need to edit the query to make it check the last names after the result of checking the first names is null. here is what I did but didn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM students WHERE first_name ILIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = pg_query($con, $sql);
if(pg_num_rows($result) == 0)
$sql = "SELECT last_name FROM students WHERE last_name ILIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following modification:
Its just an example from PHP manual please change the queries accordingly

```
<?php
  $result=pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM x WHERE a=b;");
  if  (!$result) {
    echo "query did not execute";
  }
  $rs = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
  if (!$rs) {
    echo "0 records"
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OR condition:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM students 
WHERE first_name ILIKE '%$query%'
   OR last_name ILIKE '%$query%';
```

You should also read up on the term "SQL Injection". Your code is vulnerable.